# Swift, could not cast value of type

Tags: ios, swift

I created a subclass of `UICollectionViewController` and called it `LibraryCollectionViewController`, and marked both checkboxes for the project and test. Also it's storyboard id is `LibraryCollectionViewController` and set its corresponding class on interface builder.

Being new to **Swift** and **iOS Testing** I went and attempted to instantiate said view controller inside my test case as follows:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let libraryCollectionVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LibraryCollectionViewController") as! LibraryCollectionViewController
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'MyApp.LibraryCollectionViewController' (0x1010b01f0) to 'MyAppTests.LibraryCollectionViewController' (0x10bd7f580).
```

So it is clear that it isn't casting, but as I'm still new to Swift, I find myself unable to determine if the error itself is being caused by:

1. I did something wrong when creating the subclass and I'm referencing a different one (Ergo the MyApp.[vc] vs MyAppTests.[vc])
2. The casting using `as!` is incorrect
3. Any other reason

Any help would be appreciate, thanks in advance.

**Update 1:** When I was creating the view controller, the last step shows 2 checkboxes under a **Target** header, I enabled both of them, could that be the cause?

Comment: Did you define the custom class in IB? (btw, I think it should be return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle().)

Comment: In IB I set the Class (below "Custom Class" header) to LibraryCollectionViewController.  I'll try the bundle

Comment: @matthias Using bundle gave same result :(

Comment: I think that the cause is that you enable both (maybe). MyAppTests try disable this one

Comment: maybe this helps UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)) http://www.iosmike.com/2014/08/unit-testing-viewcontrollers-in-swift.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My problem was I was referencing `NSBundle.mainBundle()` from the unit tests whereas I needed to use:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: self.classForCoder)
```

Edit: 2022, using SwiftPM in AppCode, with a `resources` key in my `Package.swift`

```
let bundle = Bundle.module
```

Answer (score 7):

This can happen if a class is a member of *two* targets (maybe two frameworks?) - and your app is somehow referencing one framework while the unit test target is referencing the second target.

So one of the compiled artefacts has a fully-qualified type `Framework1.MyClass` while the other is `Framework2.MyClass` - and they're *different classes* at runtime because they have different namespaces. (Even though both classes are compiled from the same Swift source file)

Comment: This is a nice and logic explanation but is there also a solution to fix this because I've got this exact problem.

Comment: Sure. You need to think about which target the class _needs_ to be included in, and which targets are dependent on other targets. Example: you have a swift file included in both your _app_ target and your _unit test_ target. That will lead to _two_ classes being generated from that one file. But that code is already available to the _unit test_ target, by virtue of it having a dependency on the _app_ target - so you can remove it from the unit test target.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Open `LibraryCollectionViewController.swift`
- Press *Option* + *Command* + *1* to open *File Inspector*
- Find *Target Membership* section
- Check `MyApp`

Answer (score 0):

You must not check both the targets for the view controller. You must enable only the project target for the view controller. You must import the class module in the test case file like @testable import myprojectname instead of enabling both the targets.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue because i was using navigation controller
Try this:

1. Delete embeded navigation controller
2. Bind those two view controllers directly

i hope it works

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue. You need to:

1. Delete your class and it's file.
2. Open your xcdatamodeld file.
3. Select the class that causing issues.
4. Click on "Editor" on Xcode.
5. Click on "Create NSManagedObject Subclass", it will recreate the class for you.